# need to show asp.net message box (after validating data with database) Not immediately after button click

Tags: asp.net

I need to show asp.net message box with yes and no (after validating the data with database)

My Requirement is 
 Before inserting of any data into Database(I need to check the data is present is DB on that data)

If data is present I need to show message box stating that data exists on the same day ? Are you sure want to save the data or cancel the

Not immediately after button click

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need help with validation? 
Otherwise you just need to

```
If(isValid){
 //Show MessageBox
}
```

Check validation first, if its valid show the messagebox.

Comment: My Requirement is 
 Before inserting of any data into Database(I need to check the data is present is DB on that data)

If data is present I need to show message box stating that data exists on the same day ? Are you sure want to save the data or cancel the

Answer (score 1):

On btn save_click.first check that data exists or not if exists then show message else save it. You can do like this:

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");
            con.Open();
            string query = "Select count(*) from AD_Organisation where OrgName=@a";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", txtorgname.Text.ToString());

            int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();

            if (count > 0)
            {
               //show message that the data already exists
               //call javascript
            }
            else
            {
              //insert command  
            }
```

For popup message you can use the javascript :

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function showalert() {
      alert('Data already exists');
      return false;
  }
</script>
```

For calling the javascript message use

```
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "display",  "showalert('msg');", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harpreet Singh

Here My question is I need to validate after button click (I need to show Pop up box if there is a duplicate data otherwise I should not show)

here how can I use textchanged Its not related at all

and Big Thumbs down for the ppl who vote down for my question
if you know the answer then could have answer y u ppl vote down without knowing the answer

Comment: now check my previous answer for your solution